# Allow exception for dependent (secondary) data validation

Tags: excel, list, validation

I am trying to make a form that will give users a list of possible defects to choose from when reporting a customer complaint.  First they will choose from a list of regions on the product where the problem exists and then they will choose from a list of possible defects which will populate based on the location selected in the first list. I have made the list of regions as comprehensive as possible but I feel that it is likely that something will arise where I have not forseen this issue as a possibility.  As such I would like to include an "Other" option in the location drop down list which, when selected, would change the second data entry point from a data validation list to allowing the user to typ anything the user would like to add.  Is this possible to have the type of data validation dependent on a condition?

Comment: Are you creating a User Form in VBA, or are you adding data Validation rules to cells in Excel?

Comment: Data Validation in a cell in Excel.  I was trying to avoid user forms if not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Dependent dropdown lists validation. Reference youtube video [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7cHgsFirLk) and [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwFWCs5y4Os)

You can mention "Others" option on the top of the source list for the first (Location) validation. You can then add data validation for the first list using named range with offset function. This will allow you to freely add other locations at the bottom of the list.

For the second column validation, you can enter formula skipping the first ("Others") cell in the location list.

In the image below, validation source list for column D is $A$2:$A$10 and validation list formula for Column E is `=IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$10,$D2)>0,$B$2:$B$10,$E2)`

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you....I see what you're saying, howevr, is there a way to prevent the options for (in your example) "Defect" and "s" from showing up in the dropdown list?  Ideally, if "Other" were chosen, I'd like the dropdown list to contain no selectable choices, though I'd be willing to accept only blanks.

Comment: Please see answer edited .. formula referring to the current cell in if condition not true case. So, you will not see any dropdown list values for "Others" Location