# Excel data validation only for some rows

Tags: excel, validation, conditional-statements

I have, what seems to me, an easy question to answer, but I cannot find the answer online yet without using VBA.

I have two columns, A and B.
Column A contains a fruit, column B a number. I want to apply data validation (i.e. a drop down list) for column B only in case the value of A is apple. So for other fruits, the user should just be able to enter any value.

Important: When I apply sorting to the complete table, validation should still work.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: What sort of output do you want?  A change in fill to red if invalid, conditional formatting, is easy.

Comment: Are you talking about a list or conditional formatting

Comment: A drop - down list, so not conditional formatting. So if Apple in A, then I should only be able to enter a certain list. If banana in A, then any value.

Comment: Refer almost [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295082/allow-exception-for-dependent-secondary-data-validation). For exception, refer same cell .. For example B2 list validation formula `=IF(A2="Apple",List,IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2))`

Comment: Thank you all. I went for Naresh' solution. Urdearboy also thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` you can build your validation list by making use of a helper column. The set up will be something like:

- Columns `A:B` contains your data
- Cell `D2` is the input (fruit: where **A** is **Apple**)
- Cell `E2` is the data validation list
- Column `F:F` is your help column 'Values'

---

- In `F2 = IF($D$2="A",UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9="A")),$B$2:$B$9)`
- Data Validation Formula in `E2 = INDIRECT("F2:F"&COUNTA(F:F),TRUE)`

  [image]

---

You can hide your helper column if needed *(or place it in the last column out of sight)*