# Have cell set to static value OR data validation list depending on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to have a cell either be set to a specific static value or have a full list depending on the value in another cell - seems like it has to be done via VBA but not sure of exact code.

Basic scenario is as follows:
If A1 = On
Then B2 should have a list of 3 options to choose from

If A1 = Off
Then B2 should be "N/A" and not have a list to choose from

The methodology ideally would be repeatable across other cells dependent on A1 that would have their own unique lists (e.g., C2, D2, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: It seems A1 and A2 are mutually exclusive (both cannot be true at once). either A1 will be ON or A2 will be OFF. Then you can use if formula for data "list"validation. Like `=IF(AND(A1="ON",A2<>"OFF"),LIST,"")`. So, if the list is in E1:E3 then `=IF(AND(A1="ON",A2<>"OFF"),$E$1:$E$3,"")`

Comment: Clarified the above, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then also the same formula could be applied with a little change. like `=IF(A1="ON",$E$1:$E$3,"")` .. OR .. May be you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62295438/9808063) ?